# Lipschitz functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hello,

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, it is very easy to find its Lipschitz constant. Is there any way to extend this to functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (or similar)?

Comment: You probably mean "continuously differentiable" (i.e. differentiable with continuous first derivative) and "local Lipschitz constants" (see Wikipedia page on Lipschitz for more details).  In which case, the answer is "Yes".

Comment: It is not true that any differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz: $f(x) = x^2$ is a counterexample.  A _continuously_ differentiable function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz, because its derivative is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f = (f_1,\ldots,f_n): [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable function.  (See the comments above for an explanation as to why the hypotheses have been strengthened.)

For $1 \leq i \leq n$, let

$L_i = \max_{x \in [a,b]} |f_i'(x)|$,

so that, by the Mean Value Theorem, for $x,y \in [a,b]$,

$|f_i(x)-f_i(y)| = |f_i'(c)||x-y| \leq L_i |x-y|$.

Then, taking the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$,

$|f(x)-f(y)|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |f_i(x)-f_i(y)|^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n L_i^2) \ |x-y|^2$,

so

$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^n L_i^2)} \ |x-y|$.

Thus we can take

$L = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n L_i^2}$.

Since all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent -- i.e., differ at most by a multiplicative constant -- the choice of norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ will change the expression of the Lipschitz constant $L$ in terms of the Lipschitz constants $L_i$ of the components, but not whether $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: In my answer above, I interepreted "its Lipschitz constant" as "an explicit constant which makes the function Lipschitz", not the _least_ such constant.  Off-hand it seems that the one-dimensional constants $L_i$ I gave are sharp but that $L$ I gave need not be.  This makes me think that Leonid's answer is better than mine...

Answer (score 2):

In fact a statement similar to what was described by Pete Clark is true for all normed vector spaces:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces. A (total) differentiable function $f:X\to Y$ is Lipschitz iff its derivative is bounded. Every upper bound for the differential is a Lipschitz constant.

One direction follows from the mean value theorem:
$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq \|Df(\xi)\|\cdot\|x-y\|$ for some $\xi$ on the straight line from $x$ to $y$.

The other follows immediately from
$Df(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x+h)}{\|h\|}$

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way to do this computation (which generally gives more precise information) is to use the formula

$ f(x + h) - f(x) = [ \int_0^1 Df(x + th) dt ] h$

Also, the formula for $Df(x)$ in Hahn's post above is not correct.